# ng-init with $rootScope variable, initialization issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a rootscope variable

```
//we keep it false here, on HTML page if any line item is displayed in edittable form,it will be initialized to True
        $rootScope.varToDecideDispalyofSaveButtonOn10A =false;
```

I am trying to initializing it on markup page

```
.
.
.
<tr class="BG8" ng-if="(obj.lineItemEditableForPM)" ng-init="varToDecideDispalyofSaveButtonOn10A='true'">   
.
.
.
```

Although ng-if here is true and the tr  is created, but the variable is not defined, Why?

Comment: use ng-controller instead...

Comment: ng-controller for initialization ?

Comment: `ng-if` creates a new scope, and the property gets added on it. Maybe you are trying to access this property from outside the ng-if scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `ng-if` This directive creates new child scope. here is the [DOC](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

so you can achieve this by creating a object in rootScope instead of plain variable, then first the angular will search `something.varToDecideDispalyofSaveButtonOn10A` in the child scope, and after find there is no `something.varToDecideDispalyofSaveButtonOn10A` in the child scope it will search the `something.varToDecideDispalyofSaveButtonOn10A` in the parent scope. but if u use a plain variable ( as u tried with out the object) angular will know there is nothing called `varToDecideDispalyofSaveButtonOn10A` and without searching it in parent scope it will create a child scope variable called `varToDecideDispalyofSaveButtonOn10A`

```
<tr class="BG8" ng-if="(obj.lineItemEditableForPM)" ng-init="something.varToDecideDispalyofSaveButtonOn10A=true">
```

in Controller

```
$rootScope.something = {};
$rootScope.something.varToDecideDispalyofSaveButtonOn10A =false;
```

**OR**

you can archive by referencing the parent scope inside the child scope by using `$parent` as below

```
<tr class="BG8" ng-if="(obj.lineItemEditableForPM)" ng-init="$parent.varToDecideDispalyofSaveButtonOn10A=true">
```

**OR**

you can achieve this without using `ng-init`

```
<tr class="BG8" ng-if="(obj.lineItemEditableForPM ? (varToDecideDispalyofSaveButtonOn10A = true) : false)">
```

in this case your going to change the value of `varToDecideDispalyofSaveButtonOn10A` according to value of `obj.lineItemEditableForPM`. **if `obj.lineItemEditableForPM` true**, then angular will search for `varToDecideDispalyofSaveButtonOn10A`in the child scope and then the parent scope. because your not supposing to initialize the variable as above two cases. **if `obj.lineItemEditableForPM` false**, then just `return false` without changing the value of `varToDecideDispalyofSaveButtonOn10A`.

Here is a [Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HoEQlgcChXEfaj8DCbUi?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

a common pitfall in angular js, is using primitive variables in a scope, and trying to change it from a scope inhering from it, (any scope inherits from $rootScope).

the reason this wont work, is a primitive variable is not a reference (only objects and arrays are references), and therefore, the inherited scope gets a new variable with the same name.

so you should use a object whenever you want to take advantage of scope inheritance (it could actually be a good convention to always do that):

```
$rootScope.SomeVars = { varToDecideDispalyofSaveButtonOn10A : false };
```

and in the view

```
<tr class="BG8" ng-if="(obj.lineItemEditableForPM)" ng-init="SomeVars.varToDecideDispalyofSaveButtonOn10A='true'">
```

Comment: and BTW, you should write: 
    SomeVars.varToDecideDispalyofSaveButtonOn10A=true, with no Apostrophes

Comment: yes, to make variable true type of Boolean, my code is actually making it true type of String. :) Thanks